# C# XML Parsing - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing

I am trying to Parse the following XML:

```
<connector_attribute_validation>
    <use_ssl>
       <required>1</required>
       <type>1</type>
    </use_ssl>
    <size>
        <required>1</required>
        <type>1</type>
    </size>
 </connector_attribute_validation>
```

My code is as follows:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> ValidateConnectorAttributes(string xmlString)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> validation = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
            foreach (XElement attribute in root.Elements())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> attributeInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (XElement attributeInformation in attribute.Elements())
                {
                    attributeInfo.Add(attributeInformation.Name.LocalName, attributeInformation.Value);
                }
                validation.Add(attribute.Name.LocalName, attributeInfo);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Attribute in validation)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Attribute.Key + " : ");
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> AttributeValues in Attribute.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(AttributeValues.Key + " : " + AttributeValues.Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("=========");
            }
            return validation;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

What am I doing wrong here? My goal is to convert the XML into a dictionary within a dictionary.
So I'm looking for something like:

```
<use_ssl, <required, 1> <type, 1>>
```

The exact XML I am trying to parse is as follows:

```
<connector_attributes_validations>
<use_ssl>
        <required>0</required>
    <type>string</type> 
    <default></default>
    <valid_values>Yes|No</valid_values>
  </use_ssl>
  <page_size>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>int</type>
    <default>500</default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </page_size>
  <retry_count>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>int</type>
    <default>3</default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </retry_count>
  <query_timeout>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>int</type>
    <default>600</default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </query_timeout>
  <domain_name>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>string</type>
    <default></default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </domain_name>
  <ad_account_searchbase>
    <required>0</required>
    <type>string</type>
    <default></default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </ad_account_searchbase>
  <ad_account_searchfilter>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>string</type>
    <default></default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </ad_account_searchfilter>
  <ad_group_searchbase>
    <required>0</required>
    <type>string</type>
    <default></default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </ad_group_searchbase>
  <ad_group_searchfilter>
    <required>0</required>
    <type>string</type>
    <default></default>
    <valid_values></valid_values>
  </ad_group_searchfilter>
</connector_attributes_validations>
```

I added a shortened version because both are not working for me and I do not understand why. Same error: Data at root level is invalid.

Comment: I just tried the code and the XML string you posted, no errors are appearing. Are there any other methods you are passing the XML through?

Comment: I am not using any other method. All methods are commented out.

Comment: Is the XML that you pasted above the EXACT same as what is being read in by your program?

Comment: Can you please post how you tried my code?

Comment: I copied it from here, posted it in my IDE, then copied the XML you posted and set it as a string and passed the string to the method.  All ran successfully.

Comment: Please check the edit I just made. That's the entire XML. I shortened it to see if there was a problem in the rest of the XML but it's not working for the shortened version I posted either.

Comment: That ran successfully too.  If you are reading this from an XML file there is a chance something is getting messed up when you're reading it in to memory.

Comment: Ok WOW. Now that I posted it as a string it works. It is not working when I was getting the string from the file itself.

Comment: Ok, that is definitely pointing to an issue you're having with the code that's reading it from the file.  Can you post that, and I'd be glad to help you get it figured out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work. It seems I was not reading from the file correctly. Previously I had string XML = @"*path*"
When it should have been string XML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(*Path*);

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

He is another method :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fFILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> dict = doc.Root
                .Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y.Elements()
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Name.LocalName, b => (string)b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```